# JQuery ajax is throwing 403 forbidden error because of wrongly configured .htaccess when using index.html

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

Xampp
Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.11

I have created a simple blog using Hugo static generator. The site is published in "public" folder and a host (blog.test) has been created. At the bottom I have a simple newsletter registration form. I'm using JQuery ajax to post data to "subscribe.php", which is present at the root folder.

```js
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/subscribe.php",
        data: {"email" : $("#email").val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        ...
```

Initially ajax call was not at all working. A quick search pointed me to .htaccess. I don't have **index.php** but **index.html** as it's a static site. Here is my first attempt for .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subscribe.php
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the error **403 forbidden** is showing up. I did couple of other changes in .htaccess but still the same error. Any pointer for the problem?

Cheers

Comment: Why did you forbid the post requests for `subscribe.php` file?

Comment: Just a typo, It's not working with [L] also. Tried various other ways but still no luck.

Comment: Your ajax request should work even without `htaccess` if the file the ajax sends request to exists.